# Как сохранить переменные так, чтобы потом использовать в вычислениях

Tags: javascript, global-variables

[image: Сам калькулятор]

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var screen = document.querySelector('.screen');

console.log(screen.innerHTML);
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

  var btnElem = buttons[i];

  btnElem.onclick = function() {
    var active = this.innerText;
    if (active <= 10 && !undefined) {
      screen.innerText = active;
    } else if (active == 'CE' || 'AC') {
      screen.innerText = '0';
    } else {
      console.log('Code Error');
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calc">
    <div class="top-part">
      <div class="screen">This is my screen</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-part">
      <div class="keys">
        <button class="btn clear">AC</button>
        <button class="btn clear">CE</button>
        <button class="btn operator">%</button>
        <button class="btn operator">/</button>
        <button class="btn">7</button>
        <button class="btn">8</button>
        <button class="btn">9</button>
        <button class="btn operator">X</button>
        <button class="btn">4</button>
        <button class="btn">5</button>
        <button class="btn">6</button>
        <button class="btn operator">-</button>
        <button class="btn">1</button>
        <button class="btn">2</button>
        <button class="btn">3</button>
        <button class="btn large-btn">+</button>
        <div class="empty"></div>
        <button class="btn">0</button>
        <button class="btn">.</button>
        <button class="btn result">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы у меня переменные сохранялись и можно
 было бы их после этого использовать для вычислений. Знаю, что очень глупый вопрос, но все же.
Хотелось бы, чтобы если набираешь 5 и 1 на экране было 51, а не перезаписывалось.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

Вместо того, чтобы переписывать значение на экране:

```
screen.innerText = active;
```

Просто добавьте его к уже текущему значению:

```
screen.innerText = screen.innerText+active;
```

Но придётся встроить проверку на то, чтобы стартовое значение "This is my screen" стиралось, аналогично нужно будет проверять на то, что вы не добавляете к нулю.

Также рекомендую сделать скрытый элемент (со стилем CSS display: none;) например:

```
<span id="memory" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Который будет использоваться для запоминания набранных чисел после нажатия знаков арифметических операций (+ - * / =).

Comment: Спасибо за направление на путь истинный :)